# Amazon S3 uploader using gwt

Tags: gwt, jar, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

This is what I've done.

I created an S3 uploader in and exported it as a .jar file.
I tried to import this jar file in a gwt project but it always throw me a runtime error.
Our package name is com.soul.uploader and class name is UpLoader.
Here is the error.

> failed to import com.soul

Here is the xml file I used for the S3 project

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module> 
     <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
     <source path="uploader"></source>
    </module>
```

I just wonder how can I import the jar file to the gwt project.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need the UpLoader class on the client-side (JavaScript/Browser) or on the server-side (Servlet/Backend)?

Comment: If it is client side code do not forget to use and add inherit tag in module.gwt.xml file. Also do not try to import server code into client package aka that needs to go into javascript post gwt compilation.